# I want to get the IP address like if VPN is activate than it will get this VPN IP adress in correct format

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to get IP address in my app but if VPN is on it will not give the correct IP address that VPN have.

```
try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
                    textView.setText(ip);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Android device usually has more than one network interface and can have more than one IP address at the time. For example my device has 25 interfaces and 3 IP's!

```
0 = {NetworkInterface@6045} "name:dummy0 (dummy0)"
1 = {NetworkInterface@6053} "name:r_rmnet_data2 (r_rmnet_data2)"
2 = {NetworkInterface@6054} "name:r_rmnet_data3 (r_rmnet_data3)"
3 = {NetworkInterface@6055} "name:r_rmnet_data0 (r_rmnet_data0)"
4 = {NetworkInterface@6056} "name:lo (lo)"
5 = {NetworkInterface@6057} "name:r_rmnet_data1 (r_rmnet_data1)"
6 = {NetworkInterface@6058} "name:wlan0 (wlan0)"
7 = {NetworkInterface@6059} "name:usb0 (usb0)"
8 = {NetworkInterface@6060} "name:sit0 (sit0)"
9 = {NetworkInterface@6061} "name:rmnet_data7 (rmnet_data7)"
10 = {NetworkInterface@6062} "name:rmnet_data0 (rmnet_data0)"
11 = {NetworkInterface@6063} "name:p2p0 (p2p0)"
12 = {NetworkInterface@6064} "name:tun1 (tun1)"
13 = {NetworkInterface@6065} "name:rmnet_data2 (rmnet_data2)"
14 = {NetworkInterface@6066} "name:rmnet_data1 (rmnet_data1)"
15 = {NetworkInterface@6067} "name:rmnet_data4 (rmnet_data4)"
16 = {NetworkInterface@6068} "name:rmnet_data3 (rmnet_data3)"
17 = {NetworkInterface@6069} "name:rmnet_data6 (rmnet_data6)"
18 = {NetworkInterface@6070} "name:rmnet_data5 (rmnet_data5)"
19 = {NetworkInterface@6071} "name:r_rmnet_data8 (r_rmnet_data8)"
20 = {NetworkInterface@6072} "name:r_rmnet_data6 (r_rmnet_data6)"
21 = {NetworkInterface@6073} "name:r_rmnet_data7 (r_rmnet_data7)"
22 = {NetworkInterface@6074} "name:r_rmnet_data4 (r_rmnet_data4)"
23 = {NetworkInterface@6075} "name:r_rmnet_data5 (r_rmnet_data5)"
24 = {NetworkInterface@6076} "name:rmnet_ipa0 (rmnet_ipa0)"
```

Only one interface from this list belongs to VPN. In my case it is `tun1`.

Your code gives incorrect IP address because it puts *all* matching addresses in `TextView`, but you'll see only last one.

So to get correct VPN address you just need to find an interface that corresponds to your VPN connection. The following code snippet will print you all device's IP's and one that belongs to your VPN interface (of course if your VPN tool creates `tun*` interface):

```java
if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
    Log.i("TAG", "Found new IP: " + ip + " at " + intf.getName());

    if (intf.getName().contains("tun")) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Found VPN address! " + ip);
    }
}
```

Comment: which are the other possible interfaces a VPN tool can create?

Comment: when connected to a wlan which interface will be used?